# What does an equation of the form $y'=f(t)$ called?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

My teacher asked which one of these equations is the form of a first order linear differential equation: $y'=f(t)$, or $y'+y\,g(t)=f(t)$, or $y''+y^2\,g(t)=f(t)$.

My teacher said $y'+y\,g(t)=f(t)$ is the correct answer. But isn't $y'=f(t)$ also a first order linear differential equation?

Comment: Yes.  The first equation is a special case of the second equation, namely when $g(t)=0$.

Comment: "Form" means the most general form, so that is why the second equation is "better".

Comment: Yes, the first is a first order equation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $y, y', y'', y''', ...$ occur linearly (power one) in an ODE then it is a linear equation. First and second are linear and the third one is non-linear because of $y^2$.